# Upgradability of smart contract

Tags: contract-upgrading

This is a limitation of an article that proposed a smart contract in healthcare sector:

In Ethereum blockchain, smart contracts are stored on-chain, making
them immutable. However, this poses a major challenge in the development process of smart contracts,
as immutability makes them lack upgradability. Once smart contracts are developed and deployed, they can no longer be modified. Therefore, it is not possible to patch security vulnerabilities or software bugs with an update.

I want to define it as a hypothesis for my dissertation and try to solve it, but I don't know that it could be a good topic or not and it could be solved or not and how could it be solved

Could you please help me and answer this questions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, there are various architectural patterns to solve this problem.

Yes, smart contracts are immutable. But the trick is that you can use multiple smart contracts together to create certain functionality. Then you can replace some of the contracts with new ones while simply updating a new address to use for the other contracts - so you switch one contract and tell the other contracts to refer to the new version of the contract.

You can read more about a popular pattern, proxy pattern, for example here: https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/ . Also there are many articles about "upgradable contracts" around, here's one decent looking: https://medium.com/cardstack/upgradable-contracts-in-solidity-d5af87f0f913